# Mono 4.4.0.40 on CentOS 6.7 x64 fails compilation with SigAbrt

Tags: centos, mono

I am trying to build the mono Source from Github. I've downloaded the latest tagged release which is 4.4.0.40.

I've run the following commands:

```
./autogen.sh
make get-monolite-latest
make
```

But I get the following error:

```
* Assertion at domain.c:718, condition `mono_defaults.runtimetype_class != 0' not met

Native stacktrace:

        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x4ac44a]
        /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf7e0) [0x7f19b37f47e0]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x7f19b326d625]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175) [0x7f19b326ee05]
        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x63f2fe]
        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x63f0eb]
        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x63f24c]
        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x5abeb6]
        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x426546]
        /usr/local/bin/mono(mono_main+0x37f) [0x47e5af]
        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x4205c8]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f19b3259d5d]
        /usr/local/bin/mono() [0x420459]

Debug info from gdb:

Mono support loaded.
[New LWP 50147]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
0x00007f19b37f437d in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  2 Thread 0x7f19acbff700 (LWP 50147)  0x00007f19b37f068c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
* 1 Thread 0x7f19b45a7780 (LWP 50146)  0x00007f19b37f437d in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f19acbff700 (LWP 50147)):
#0  0x00007f19b37f068c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000607b8c in thread_func () at ../../mono/utils/mono-os-mutex.h:105
#2  0x00007f19b37ecaa1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007f19b332393d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f19b45a7780 (LWP 50146)):
#0  0x00007f19b37f437d in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004ac4d4 in mono_handle_native_sigsegv () at mini-exceptions.c:2348
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x00007f19b326d625 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f19b326ee05 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x000000000063f2fe in monoeg_log_default_handler ()
#6  0x000000000063f0eb in monoeg_g_logv ()
#7  0x000000000063f24c in monoeg_assertion_message ()
#8  0x00000000005abeb6 in mono_init_internal () at domain.c:718
#9  0x0000000000426546 in mini_init () at mini-runtime.c:3602
#10 0x000000000047e5af in mono_main ()
#11 0x00000000004205c8 in main () at main.c:20

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

make[6]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Aborted (core dumped)
*** The compiler 'mcs' doesn't appear to be usable.
*** Trying the 'monolite' directory.
Bootstrap compiler: Mono C# compiler version 4.3.3.0
./../jay/jay: 8 shift/reduce conflicts.
mkdir -p -- ../class/lib/basic/
make[7]: *** No rule to make target `../../external/ikvm/reflect/*.cs', needed by `../class/lib/basic/basic.exe'.  Stop.
make[6]: *** [do-all] Error 2
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: *** [profile-do--basic--all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [profiles-do--all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/mono-mono-4.4.0.40/runtime'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/mono-mono-4.4.0.40'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am running `CentOS 6.7 x64 kernel 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64`

Has anyone else had this and managed to resolve it?